# How to change style of header in AMSBook class

Tags: header-footer, amsbook

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

It produces on the top of the second page

[image]

I would like to change the `\textsc` style in the header to a normal font style. How do I achieve this?

Comment: the answer by @egreg is correct.  however, it doesn't really make clear the fact that the font of the running heads isn't `\textsc`, it's actual uppercase.  the reason for this is that mathematicians tend to put math symbols and variables in their titles, and if small caps were used for headers, the math would be ridiculously too large.  this may not give optimum results typographically, but in practical terms is much easier to accomplish and faster to process, although the latter doesn't make much difference nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the uppercasing part from `\chapterrunhead`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\chapterrunhead}{\uppercasenonmath\@tempa}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]